# Network not Learning when Training Fully Connected Layers in Caffe

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am quite new to Caffe. What I am doing is I have a set of features for two datasets (cars and flowers).

1. The feature size is 256-D for each image samples.
2. Training Set: 500 Car images and 1200 Flower images
3. Test set: 100 Car images and 200 Flower images

Basically, the problem is a binary classification problem. My caffe *train.prototxt* file is as follows:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "train.txt"
    batch_size: 40
  }
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "test.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "fc1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 256
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "sigmoid1"
  type: "Sigmoid"
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "sigmoid1"
}
layer {
  name: "fc2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "sigmoid1"
  top: "fc2"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 256
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "sigmoid2"
  type: "Sigmoid"
  bottom: "fc2"
  top: "sigmoid2"
}
layer {
  name: "fc3"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "sigmoid2"
  top: "fc3"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "fc3"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc3"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

I am reading the data using HDF5 layer and passing it to 3-Fully connected layers of 256-256-2 with activation function of sigmoid. (I also changed to ReLU but results didnt change).

```
The solver prototxt is: 
 net: "train.prototxt"
test_iter: 100
test_interval: 200
base_lr: 0.010
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.00005
lr_policy: "inv"
gamma: 0.00001
delta: 1e-8
#test_compute_loss: true
power: 0.75
display: 100
#stepsize: 1000
max_iter: 10000
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "sample"
solver_mode: GPU
```

The problem is that this architecture is not working which I believe is due to the fact that the net is not learning anything.

This plot shows the accuracy plot for first 500 iteration which clearly shows that nothing constructive is happening.

[image: plot]

To test if the datasets, features are not wrong I trained a linear SVM using the features on LibSVM and it works with 84% accuracy.

Perhaps my network setup is not correct and it would be great if someone could help me get this working. Thanks

**--------------------**

**Update:** Using PReLU as I get the following plot. I reduced the num_output from 256 to 128:
[image]

Comment: you overfit. you have far too many parameters and far too few examples.

Comment: Too many parameters you mean the weights?

Comment: Also don't use sigmoid, use ReLU instead.

Comment: @Shai sorry I think I am bit confused as you mentioned too many parameters. Other than increasing the dataset size is there anyother suggestion you can make which can help increase the accuracy?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thanks for you suggestion. Infact I used ReLU first but the results were pretty much similar as shown in the graph. I feel that the problem is overfitting as Shai mentioned.

Comment: For training from scratch sometimes it's better to use `"PReLU"` rather than `"ReLU"`

Comment: @Shai thanks for your suggestion. I added the plot of using PReLU. I feel overfitting is a serious problem still. I wonder if my network for training and test is correct. Can you please take a look :) I will try to increase my dataset. Is uneven dataset a problem (eg. 500 for cars and 1300 for flowers)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to shuffle your input data, use a smaller network, and maybe add some sort of regularization like dropouts.

Answer (score 0):

You are overfitting, use some pretrained CNN (CIFAR for example) and finetune on your set.